# View a list of objects in a crystal report within razor application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, crystal-reports

i have an asp.net mvc4 application with Razor, in which i 'd like to add a report `Crystal Reports`. So i create a folder AspxPages and i added an `Aspx` view. Besides, i have in my models the class Result that i'd like to view a `List<Result>` like this:

```
List<Element> elem_list = notre_chef.Get_ListElement_By_Project(id_project);
List<Result> model = new List<Result>();
foreach (Element e in elem_list) 
{ 
   Result _r = new Result(e.Id_element);
   model.Add(_r);
}
string strReportName;
string rapportName;

strReportName = "Current.rpt";
rapportName = "Resultat Actuel du test";

ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
// the Rapport path "Rpts/strReportName"

string strRptPath = 
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/") + "Rpts//" 
        + strReportName;

rd.Load(strRptPath);
foreach (Result res in model)
{
    rd.SetParameterValue("category", res.Catégorie);
    rd.SetParameterValue("sf", res.Sous_fonctionnalité);
    rd.SetParameterValue("concept", res.Concept);
    rd.SetParameterValue("expert", res.Expert);
    rd.SetParameterValue("property", res.Propriétés);
    rd.SetParameterValue("f", res.Fonction);
    rd.SetParameterValue("avis", res.Avis);
    rd.SetParameterValue("justification", res.Justification);
    if (final == 0)
    {
       rd.SetParameterValue("titre", "Resultat actuel du test");
    }
    else
    {
        rd.SetParameterValue("titre", "Resultat final du test");
    }
}
rd.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat,
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response, false, rapportName);

return RedirectToAction("Display_Chef_Attempt", new{id_project = id_project});
```

In the report, I added the required fields. My problem is that only the last object `Result` in the list is shown in the report not all the list in different pages.

So what is the problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: It seems like you do set the parameters foreach value in your `model`, but since you set it on the same object (`rd`), only the values from your last iteration stick... (The others get overwritten).

Comment: @bump how can i fix it, i'm beginner with reporting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like bump sais you are trying to populate your paramenters with data, and of course the report will use just the last record.

what you are looking for is to set the datasource of the report document that should be something like this:

```
rd.SetDataSource(model);
```

Here you have a complete sample how to pass a generic collection to crystal. [Crystal Report with generic Collection](http://kkanagasubramanian.wordpress.com/2010/08/02/crystal-report-with-generic-collection/), this article should help you.